# Laravel 5.4 routing for same prefix group but different middleware giving error

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I need all the route under same prefix **manager** with one middleware for guest **manager_guest** and another for logged in user **manager_auth**.
This code bellow is my route web.php file.

Is there any other way ?

My routes:

```
Route::prefix('manager')->group(['middleware' => 'manager_guest'], function () {
    Route::get('/register', 'Manager\RegisterController@showRegister')->name('manager.register.create');
    Route::post('/register', 'Manager\RegisterController@register')->name('manager.register.store');
    Route::get('/login', 'Manager\LoginController@showLogin')->name('manager.login.create');
    Route::post('/login', 'Manager\LoginController@login')->name('manager.login');
});

Route::prefix('manager')->group(['middleware' => 'manager_auth'], function () {
    Route::post('/logout', 'Manager\LoginController@logout')->name('manager.logout');
    Route::get('/profile', 'Manager\PageController@profile')->name('manager.profile');
});
```

Error after executing `php artisan route:list`

```
PHP Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: Array to string conversion in E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:329
Stack trace:
#0 E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(329): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Array to string...', 'E:\\laragon\\www\\...', 3
29, Array)
#1 E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(329): require()
#2 E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(285): Illuminate\Routing\Router->loadRoutes(Array)
#3 E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Router->group(Array, Array)
#4 E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\routes\web.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar->group(Array, Object(Closure))
#5 E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(329): require('E:\\laragon\\www\\...')
#6 in E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php on line 329
PHP Fatal error:  Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required 'Array' (include_path='E:\Developer\Wbserver\php\PEAR') in E:\laragon\www\laraveladmin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate
\Routing\Router.php on line 329
 
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required 'Array' (include_path='E:\Developer\Wbserver\php\PEAR')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could "factorize" your code like this:

```
Route::prefix('manager')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware(['manager_guest'])->group(function () {
        // These will be prefixed with "manager" and assigned the "manager_guest" middleware
    });

    Route::middleware(['manager_auth'])->group(function () {
        // These will be prefixed with "manager" and assigned the "manager_auth" middleware
    });

    // These will just be prefixed with "manager"
});
```

I noticed all your controllers live in the sub-namespace Manager. You can chain the methods and make your routes file even cleaner. For instance:

```
Route::prefix('manager')->namespace('Manager')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware(['manager_guest'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegister')->name('mananger.register.create');
    });

    Route::middleware(['manager_auth'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('profile', 'PageController@profile')->name('mananger.profile');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank yo very much it works .Thanks again for namespace now it looks cleaner and easy to handle . :)

Answer (score 12):

Try this instead

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manager',  'middleware' => 'manager_guest'], function() {

    });
```

Comment: I like this way of sharing route attributes. But you would need to "duplicate" this piece of code to prefix all route URIs with `manager` and assign the middleware `manager_auth`.

Comment: You're right. It only depends as matter of preferences. In general use case, I prefer using `group` as, I think, makes it more readable than using nested  `prefix`,  `namespace`,  `middleware`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me as I had a lot of routes to change, and didn't want to change namespaces. The key to making this work is "as". The downside of this being that it changes the path when using "route()", but your use of name on each route here would override that anyway.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manager', 'middleware' => ['manager_guest'], 'as' => 'manager_guest'], function() {
  ...
}

Route::group(['prefix' => 'manager', 'middleware' => ['manager_auth'], 'as' => 'manager_auth'], function() {
  ...
}
```